# GCP Load Balancer Corrupts Backend Data

Tags: google-cloud-platform

1. Running HAProxy behind GCP HTTPS Load Balancer.
2. All backends are healthy (in GCP LB and HAProxy).
3. I am able to reach HAProxy stats page over H2.
4. But when I go to reach a server proxied by HAProxy, GCP returns 502: statusDetails:  "backend_response_corrupted"
5. HAProxy http log shows 200 OK, and the correct data size.
6. Curl the backend URL from outside GCP returns the correct data.
7. HAProxy HTTP Keep Alive 620s (long as Google recommends)

Any ideas on why GCP load balancer returns 502 corrupted data?

Comment: What is H2? Do you have a protocol mismatch between GCP LB and HAProxy? Edit your question and include details on how everything is configured.

Answer (score 0):

Its explained in official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring#statusdetail_http_failure_messages) .

Quoting from the documenation:

> The HTTP response body sent by the backend has invalid chunked transfer-encoding or is otherwise corrupted